# Facebook sharer not displaying proper image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I am using facebook graph for sharing image.
please check my following page.

http://www.nilamihouse.com/arts/apetizers0

i have given 1 link for Share on facebook.

I have set meta tags for the same also:

But i am not getting proper image while the dialog opens.

When i am debugging it on following url:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nilamihouse.com%2Farts%2Fapetizers0

I am getting following message sometime.: 
"Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

og:image should be larger   Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://www.nilamihouse.com/UploadImages/045a1c25d29546839d16bfa08335e7d3.jpg' will be used instead."

**Sometimes** it works fine..Why so..?? I am facing this issue on many times.

Why this kind of random behaviour ??? Sometimes it takes proper image sometimes it gives error???

Please check my attached filed..[image: Warning]
Net time when i checked i got without any error.

[image: Without warning]

Comment: Your image http://www.nilamihouse.com/ImageResize.ashx?imgPath=UploadImages/d744de02bb784865b3caf422fa5edeae.jpg&width=400&height=400 gets delivered with `Content-Type: text/html` - see to it that your script sends the _correct_ MIME type in that header.

Comment: I have given direct path..still having problem.. check http://www.nilamihouse.com/arts/desnudo1

Comment: I think that image might be too big ...

Comment: Yes.... so should i set low resolution image ????

Comment: Not really "low", FB recommends a size of 600x600 or something I think - but yours right no might definitively be too big (2.448px × 3.264px)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by adding all my meta tags on the root (index.php) as well.
Facebook need to see it on your home page if you want it to get the right image on a specific page.